# dojo - data from sql server for datagrid and charts

Tags: sql-server-2008, dojo

I have just started getting familiar with dojo and creating widgets and have a web UI which I would like to now populate with data. My question is merely to get some references or ideas on how to do this. My databases are all sql server 2008 and I usually work with microsoft.net. I thought that I would probably have to create a service that calls the sql queries and converts the results into json and feed that into the widgets whether it be the datagrid or charts. Just not sure how to do this and if it is indeed possible to do that. Any ideas appreciated.

EDIT:

```
       store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
            url: "hof-batting.json"
        });

        ngrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            store: store,
            id: 'ngrid',
            structure: [
                { name: "Search Term", field: "searchterm", width: "10%" },
                { name: "Import Date", field: "importDate", width: "10%" }
            ]
        }, "grid");


        ngrid.startup();
```

I want to add data returned from my web service to this datagrid and use the same principle to add data to a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your describe exactly what you need to do.

We use C# to query our database to get the data and then convert it to json.  We use multiple techniques right now for json serialization.  I would recommend using JSON.NET.  It is what the .NET MVC team is going to use.  I would not use the DataContractSerialization that is currently part of .NET.

http://json.codeplex.com/

We sometimes put JSON right on the page and the javascript accesses it as a page variable.  Other times we call services in .NET.  We use WCF and we have also used an .ashx file to give the web client json data.

The structure of the json will be the contract between your dojo widgets and web server.  I would use what the chart widgets or store will need to start the process of defining the contract.

### EDIT

WCF Interface

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "/data/{service}/", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
String RetrieveData(string service, Stream streamdata);
```

The implementation returns a string that is the json.  This gets sent to the browser as json, but it's wrapped by .NET by an xml node.  I have a utility function that cleans it.

```
MyUtil._xmlPrefix = 
    '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">';
MyUtil._xmlPostfix = '</string>';

MyUtil.CleanJsonResponse = function(data) {
    // summary: 
    //    a method that cleans a .NET response and converts it 
    //    to a javascript object with the JSON. 
    //    The .NET framework, doesn't easily allow for custom serialization,
    //    so the results are shipped as a string and we need to remove the 
    //    crap that Microsoft adds to the response.
    var d = data;
    if (d.startsWith(MyUtil._xmlPrefix)) {
        d = d.substring(MyUtil._xmlPrefix.length);
    }
    if (d.endsWith(MyUtil._xmlPostfix)) {
        d = d.substring(0, d.length - MyUtil._xmlPostfix.length);
    }

    return dojo.fromJson(d);
};

// utility methods I have added to string
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) { 
  return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
};
String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) { 
  return this.slice(-str.length) == str;
};
```

Comment: thanks. do you know of any samples or links that show attempts to do this? I just got a WCF service working and now trying to convert the results to json. The challenging part it seems would be to get the json fed to the controls. I have examples of the json data hardcoded in the xml; so need to figure out how to do this. thanks for your response.

Comment: should I call the service from an .net method or can I do this from within the xml as a javascript function and how do I add it to the datagrid